# How to change default control values in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there anyway to change the default values of a control so that next time if I drag drop them, they have the new values.

For example if I change the default size and font of a text box and next time I drag drop, it has those new values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to set default (as I know), but you can copy existing control. Drag and drop while holding Control key, or usual copy/paste. New control will be exact copy of existing one, with name identifier differing by a number added to existing name.

You can also clone several controls at the same time, by selecting them all before the copy.